# 'Cannot GET /messages/' in node.js

Tags: node.js

I was learning node.js from LinkedIn learning. I was trying to build a simple chat application. Unfortunately, I am not being able to process the 'GET' message function. When I type: localhost:3000/messages, I get an error. Please guide me through my error.

My Directory is:

index.html, package.json, node modules, and server.js My code:

server.js

```
var app = express()
app.use(express.static(__dirname)) //gets the index.html file
//gets the messages
app.get('/messages', (req, res)=>{

    res.send('hello')

})
app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: works fine to me. did you import your express on top of server.js file? var express = require("express");

Comment: I tried a different way. Created a file called **server.js** and here is my code:

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported the Express library. Put this line of code, at the top of your server.js file.

```
const express = require('express');
```

Besides, make sure that another program on your computer is not using port 3000.

Comment: I did import but forgot to show here. :( If I clone the github link of the source code which is done by the tutor, then it works.

Comment: Try to change the the order. First declare the /message route, and after that declare the static files. You want to first use the Router, and if the endpoint URL doesn't match any other routes a static file will be served.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a public folder inside the node js project, and place the index.html, chat.js, css file, etc files in the public folder, but keep the server.js or index.js files in the root directory.

And add the following line in index.js or server.js file:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```